# R3F / ThreeJs :How can shadows be precomputed in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am creating a website where users should be able to create worlds in a world editor (also coded in R3F/ThreeJs).

What I would like to achieve is that when users create the world, it bakes the shadows and then displays a visually appealing version of that world on the website without sacrificing performance by calculating the shadows in real-time (similar to how it works in the game Trackmania).

How is this possible ?

I have seen that it is possible to calculate lightmaps, but to what extent is it feasible? Because depending on the number of objects, it can become very memory-intensive and even less performant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.